# Remove ALL styling/formatting from hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, href

I'm creating a navigation menu with words with different colors (`href` links). I would like the color NOT to change on any state (hover, visited etc).

I know how to set the the colors for the different states, but I would like to know the code to just leave the text color (and any other styling/formatting) as it is.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 416, accepted):

You can simply define a style for links, which would override `a:hover`, `a:visited` etc.:

```css
a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
}
```

You can also use the `inherit` value if you want to use attributes from parent styles instead:

```css
body {
  color: blue;
}
a {
  color: inherit; /* blue colors for links too */
  text-decoration: inherit; /* no underline */
}
```

Comment: The important part is the `inherit` keyword. It doesn't have 100% support unfortunately.

Comment: `initial` is also helpful when you want to css reset to the default style. This is well explained here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value)

Comment: @david, Does it still stand? Does `inherit` not work only in anciet browsers and Internet Explorer or there are difficulties in popular browsers (Chrome, Firefox) too?

Comment: Check out [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)  as well.


>> 
The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like the initial keyword in the second case.

Comment: The problem with resetting pseudo classes is that the resets are difficult to override later because of the specificity of a pseudo class selector.

Answer (score 40):

The property-value pair:

```css
a {
    all: unset;
}
```

seems cleaner in my opinion and has the advantage to work with all the selectors, e.g.:

```css
a, button /* &c... */ {
    all: unset;
}
```

Note that this will also remove the property `{cursor: pointer;}` from your link. It might or might not be what you are looking for. Simply add this property in the second case.

To learn more about the `all` shorthand, checkout this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all

As Emi said, don't forget to check for compatibility:
https://caniuse.com/css-all

Comment: Genius! This one works for underline and link color on visited...etc. The best answer IMO

Comment: I'd recommend checking browser compatibility for that approach: https://caniuse.com/css-all

Comment: But this will remove the special mouse hover icon. And it will leave the hover style.

Answer (score 6):

As Chris said before me, just an `a` should override. For example:

```css
a { color:red; }
a:hover { color:blue; }
.nav a { color:green; }
```

In this instance the `.nav a` would **always** be green, the `:hover` wouldn't apply to it.

If there's some other rule affecting it, you COULD use `!important`, but you shouldn't. It's a bad habit to fall into.

```css
.nav a { color:green !important; } /*I'm a bad person and shouldn't use !important */
```

Then it'll **always** be green, irrelevant of any other rule.

Comment: This isn't what he asked. Re-read the question. He already knows this.

Comment: @david I have re-read, pretty sure that's what he asked. This code will allow him to set a style for `a` which will prevent any changes on `:hover` (or `:visited` etc). How about instead of being a dick and rubbishing all three answers you suggest an actual solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what if the link is like this. 2 words in 2 colors, but it's just 1 link:

unique(in pink) sales(in black) 
And they should stay that color in any state. 

I coded it inline this way...

<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none" target="_blank"><span style="font-family:  Arial;font-size: 13px;color: #e91974;font-weight: lighter;">unique</span> <span style="font-family:  Arial;font-size: 13px;color: #020202;font-weight: lighter;">sales</span></a>

But there must be a cleaner. (there where many links like this in the code) 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess that's why classes were invented. @Rbijker.com

Answer (score -1):

if you state `a.redLink{color:red;}` then to keep this on hover and such add `a.redLink:hover{color:red;}`  This will make sure no other hover states will change the color of your links

Answer (score -1):

You can just use an `a` selector in your stylesheet to define all states of an anchor/hyperlink. For example:

```
a {
    color: blue;
}
```

Would override all link styles and make all the states the colour blue.

Comment: This isn't what he asked. Re-read the question. He already knows this.