# How to prevent heading tags from inheriting hyperlink styles when setting up heading anchors

Tags: html, css, google-sites

Apologies if this is a newbie question. Part of my job is to convert traditional word documents into online web documentation using Google sites.

The document I am migrating typically has a contents page, chapters and sections etc.

In HTML, I would like to have a contents page that provides clickable links to various document sections and headings - I am doing this with HTML anchors.

**The Problem:** I do not wish the text that is being linked to, to inherit the ensuing hyperlink styles. For example:

```html
<div>
<h1>Contents page:</h1>
<p><a href="#heading">Section 1: Introduction</a><p>
</div>

<section>
<h1><a name="heading">Section1: Introduction</a></h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim lectus eu risus tortor facilisi class, eleifend faucibus morbi pretium bibendum lobortis tellus hendrerit sociis litora etiam aliquet pharetra.</p>

</section>
```

Now the heading tag  appears as a hyperlink because of the  attribute, which I do not want. Instead I want it to retain its default  heading style without me having to define any override style or anything like that.

I've read something somewhere about 'all:initial' I don't know if this stuff works with HTML5/CSS3.

I'm wondering if this is an issue with Google sites only or..?

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919682/remove-all-styling-formatting-from-hyperlinks)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS way would just be:

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Anyway, if you want to do it inline, you can use:

```
<a style="all: inherit"></a>
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Contents page:</h1>
<p><a href="#heading">Section 1: Introduction</a><p>
</div>

<section>

<h1><a name="heading" style="all: inherit">Section1: Introduction</a></h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit dignissim lectus eu risus tortor facilisi class, eleifend faucibus morbi pretium bibendum lobortis tellus hendrerit sociis litora etiam aliquet pharetra.</p>

</section>
```

This makes every link look like normal text. If you just wanted your named anchor tag to be not styled (which is not styled on Chrome, so I maybe didn't quiet got your question right...) use @CBroe's answer! You don't need the `<a>` tag here. Just name the `<h1>`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer - google sites just doesn't want to accept this html, just brings up an error code 'WARNING: Your HTML contains some tags that are not permitted. These have been removed from your changes.'

Comment: What are the forbidden tags? Are they highlighted?

Comment: They are not highlighted however I do not think it likes the 'id' attribute very much, just omits them.

Comment: Ok... I've edited my answere back to the name="" solution... does it work now or is the style attribute forbidden too? In that case, i'm not sure if your problem can be solved...

Comment: Hi, I just tried - unfortunately it looks like Google sites strips out some CSS/HTML so it won't even accept 'all:inherit' attribute. Not sure if there is any work around.. but thank you for trying. Normally your solution would work..

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1><a name="heading">Section1: Introduction</a></h1>
```

You don’t need to use `<a name="heading">` to create an anchor target within the page – every element that has an id can be the target of such a hash-anchor-link as well.

So just use `<h1 id="heading">Section1: Introduction</h1>` instead, and no link styles will be applied.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer however I tried using the 'id' attribute before and it doesn't seem to work in google sites :/ I tried running your code on there, doesn't want to accept the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can come up considering the Google Sites limitations, is leaving the anchor element empty inside your `<h1>` tag, like this:

```
<h1><a name="heading"></a>Section1: Introduction</h1>
```

You can put a blank space inside: `&nbsp;`