# How to unstyle a link

Tags: html, css

I have a link in a div:

```
  <div class="parentStyle">Click me:<a>foo</a></div>
```

How do I make the link NOT have any of it's own style, so that it takes on the appearance of the parent div?

The issue is that the parent div has a blue background with white letters. Because it is a link, it is styled like a link with blue letters so I end up with blue on blue.

The parent style is added with Javascript.  So the parent is sometime styled with white letters, and sometimes not.

I need the link to keep the same look as the parent.

This is how it looks when selected:

```
<div class="k-top k-top"><span class="k-in k-state-selected">
        <a class="au-target" au-target-id="222" href="#/entity-router/entityDetails/2">
            Item 1</a>
    </span></div>
```

This is how it looks when it is not selected:

```
<div class="k-bot"><span class="k-in">
        <a class="au-target" au-target-id="234" href="#/entity-router/entityDetails/8">Item 2</a>
    </span></div>
```

Comment: Style it with `#parent a` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Add the same style from parent to the a tag

Comment: Look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919682/remove-all-styling-formatting-from-hyperlinks

Comment: The parent style is added with javascript by a framework, so I can't really do that.

Comment: What do you mean the style is added by a framework and you can't change it?

Comment: When the division is selected, then the style changes.  The background becomes blue, and the letters white.  When it is not selected, it is blue letters with white background.  I need the link to be styled in the same way.

Comment: Well, when you change the parent styles change the a tag as well. I can't see any problem :)

Comment: Create a class for styling the anchor tag and toggle that class when the parent's style changes.

Comment: Change the style of children as a callback function of parent change.

Comment: The code that changes the parent class is part of Kendo UI and I don't have access to that code.

Comment: Can you make a printscreen of the issue?

Comment: @BojanPetkovski, I understand your answer now and it worked :) If you want to post as answer, I will accept.

Comment: @GregGum Glad that I could help :)

Comment: @connexo, why do you think I made no attempt at the answer?  I did in fact put quite some time on resolving this before posting.  The use in question is for a TreeView, which turned out to be quite difficult to implement in html/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unstyle an element, but you can apply a style only when a parent has a particular style like this:

```
parentStyle  a {
    color: #fff;
    background: blue;
    /*etc.*/
}
```

This style will apply only when it is a child of an element with a class of 'parentStyle'

Answer (score 9):

You can also use this to make the link no different from the parent element's text.

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>Some normal text and a <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">link</a>.</p>
```

PS: You may need to use more styles depending on the CSS already used.

Answer (score 2):

Use css

```
div#parent a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using CSS.

Try this.

```html
<html>
  <style>
    #parent{
      background:blue;
      }
    #parent a{
      color:#fff;
      text-decoration:none;
      }
    </style>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">Click me:<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291385/how-to-unstyle-a-link">foo</a></div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Hope it will help.