# Disinherit (reset) the CSS style of a specific element?

Tags: html, css

Ok, I have a beautiful web, with its styles within a CSS and everything

But now I've found a problem, I want ONE list to be virgin, without any style inherited.

I know I can do it just giving it a `style="(...)"` so it overwrites the inherited style, but, is there any instruction / trick / something to do it without doing this?

Comment: Im confused with what your asking. Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @SamWarren "How can one fix a previously applied overzealous selector?" :) Anyway, one could also use `!important` stuff, but it would still have to be manually reset for various properties.

Comment: Of course Sam:

In my page, I have some lists inheriting style so they are shown in a beautiful way.

But then, I have one list I don't want to be shown as a "usual" list. Well, exactly I have a field near an imput  that suggests you results via AJAX (like Facebook does for example). 

I show the suggestions as a list for practical purposes, and I don't want THIS list to be shown as a list with all the styles I have defined for a usual list.

Comment: @ArcDare What selector are you using to match the lists?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I put the one of the element

Comment: @ArcDare You mean `ul { ... }` and `li { ... }`?

Comment: Related but a much more specific (isolated) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value

Comment: As to why we need this, often there's 50,000 lines of garbage coming from Twitter Boostrap and its ilk, layers upon layers of garbage (think  Envato themes.)

Answer (score 10):

The [CSS Cascading and Inheritance Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/) specification introduces ability to reset all properties at once. This is achieved by using the [`all`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#all-shorthand) shorthand property with the value of [`initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial) or [`unset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inherit-initial) depending on whether you need to reset inherited properties.

Note that these have nothing to do with browser’s default values.

The feature is available in Firefox 27+, Chrome 37+, and Opera 24+.

Until the feature is widely implemented, you can use “namespace” classes. For example, to separate layout styles from content styles, a class like `content` could be used as a namespace for all content styles.

Simplified example:

```
/* Global styles for UL lists. */
UL {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Styles for UL lists inside content block. */
.content UL {list-style: disc; margin: 1em 0 1em 35px; }
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "reset CSS properties to their browser-default values"? Initial values have the `initial` keyword, but that's different from browser defaults.

Comment: This does not solve the case where the initial value is "inherit", such as with background.  There's no way to "reset" a div's background color to what it would be on a blank page.  In other words, sandboxing is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that is solved best by avoiding it from the beginning. I try to keep [contextual (or descendant) selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector) to a minimum and I avoid using tag names as selectors. Instead I make use of classes so that my html elements (`<a>`, `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<span>`, etc) will always look like they've not been styled no matter what the context/its parent element is.

In your case, I think you can only overwrite the inherited styles as you have mentioned with the inline-style attribute or with `!important` or even better, create a `.reset` class:

```
.reset { with: auto; height: auto; padding: 0; /* etc */ }
```

All solutions mentioned above have drawbacks, so you'll need to choose your battle.

Comment: I agree. If you need this solution, you probably have a design-flaw.

Comment: "contextual selectors", one of the coolest things about CSS1 a long time ago :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this http://cleanslatecss.com/ it completely reset the target element, it's only css, no js, you just have to add a class to the target and it's all done.

The problem I found in the other answers is that nobody used `!important` so it could happen that the reset may not be applied to the element, everything is solved with cleanslate that do that for you.

Comment: http://cleanslatecss.com/ this library is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

## Shadow DOM

The feature(s) of the Shadow DOM `v1` *currently (constantly subject to change)* [have growing support](http://caniuse.com/#search=shadow%20dom%20v1), offering a wealth of possibilities, including **scoped CSS**.

> Shadow DOM `v0` was implemented in Chrome/Opera but other browser vendors are implementing `v1`.
> MS Edge status: [Under Consideration](http://status.modern.ie/shadowdom)
> Firefox status: [in-development](https://platform-status.mozilla.org/#shadow-dom)

From [Google Developers: Shadow DOM v1: Self-Contained Web Components](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom):

> Hands down the most useful feature of shadow DOM is scoped CSS:
>
> - CSS selectors from the outer page don't apply inside your component.
> - Styles defined inside don't bleed out. They're scoped to the host element.
>
> CSS selectors used inside shadow DOM apply locally to your component. In practice, this means we can use common id/class names again, without worrying about conflicts elsewhere on the page. Simpler CSS selectors are a best practice inside Shadow DOM. They're also good for performance.

Below, we [`attachShadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) to a new [`createElement( "div" )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to which we apply the [`style.all = "unset"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all#allunset) to *disinherit* `all` the rules applied to the rest of the `document`'s `div`s.

We then fill our `shadow-root` with whatever content we like, and supply any styles desired, before [`appendChild( "new_div" )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) *injects* our content into the `body`.

The result is stylistically isolated content.

```js
const new_style = document.createElement( "style" ),
      new_div = document.createElement( "div" ),
      new_list = document.createElement( "ul" ),
      new_entries = [ "Lorem", "Ipsum", "Dolor" ],
      shadow = new_div.attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
new_style.textContent = "ul { list-style: none; }";
new_div.style.all = "unset";
new_entries.forEach( ( v ) => {
  var li = document.createElement( "li" );
  li.textContent = v;
  new_list.appendChild( li );
} );
shadow.appendChild( new_style );
shadow.appendChild( new_list );
document.body.appendChild( new_div );
```

```css
body {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
ul {
  margin: 2em;
  border: 2px gray solid;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
li {
  margin: inherit;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
    <li>Qux</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```