# Inherit from root in CSS?

Tags: html, css, parent

**The scenario**

Let's say I have a sidebar where every box / widget is an li-element (not very uncommon). I have styled these li-elements with colors, paddings, margins fonts and so on.

One or a few of the boxes have their own inner li-element in their content. I don't want to inherit the styles from the box li element.

**Another scenario**

Let's say I have a page with main content containg paragraphs, lists and headings added with TinyMCE (an editor).

Then there is a "shortcode" within the content, like this: [my_superbox_module] that is replaced by custom content. That custom content contains boxes added with li-elements.

The code might look like this:

```
<p>My content</p>
<ul>
    <li>My content list item 1</li>
    <li>My content list item 2</li>
</ul>
<p>Another content</p>
<div class="my_superbox_module">
    <ul>
        <li>My superbox 1</li>
        <li>My superbox 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>Ending paragraph</p>
```

In this scenario I don't want to add a class to every ul-element because it is the content part, added with a TinyMCE editor.

**Can I inherit from root?**

Is there a way to inherit the style properties from root OR just clean it and start from scratch.

**These things I know already**

- I can clear the inner li-elements by override their CSS. That adds extra CSS-code.
- I can use > selector on the outer li-element to only target one level depth. That don't work well in some cases, for examples with nested boxes (nested li-elements).
- I can add a reset-class to the inner li-element. That adds extra HTML-code.

Is there a great solid solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean "root"? There is no "root" in CSS.

Comment: Add a special class to the li-elements you want to style. When writing CSS, target specific elements and leave the others alone, rather than target the everything and try to negate the effects in some.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall: there is a `:root` selector anyway :P

Comment: @BoltClock Ahhhhh bah humbug `:P`. But of course that doesn't seem to be the "root" the OP is talking about.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Good question. I ment to inherit from html or body.

Comment: @JimmyX Good point! However I think that fails in my "Another scenario" which I updated my post with. Write again if you have a reply to it.

Comment: @BoltClock Code added in my "Another scenario".

Comment: I take it you only want to style the `ul`s inside `.my_superbox_module`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9516657/1211187

Comment: @JimmyX Yes, that is what I want, without it being inherit whatever styles.

Comment: @MaratTanalin Thank you for that interesting reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a class? Change your selector in CSS from `li` to `li.sidebar` and add `class="sidebar"` to your `li` elements.

Comment: Good point but I think it fails in some cases. Look at my updated post in "Another scenario". I added a code example as well. Reply if you have any more ideas. Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying that you want your style to be applied to every `li` on the site, except those created by modules?

Comment: li-element on the content area should be styled as list items, bullets, left margin and so on... BUT the li-elements that are a part of the "module" should not inherit that.

Comment: Then it looks like your only real option will be to set the default style as you are and negate it on the `li` elements in the modules. Which isn't really a good way to do things, but I don't see any other options for you.