# How to force the user agent (browser) default on a property that's been overridden by a front-end framework?

Tags: css

I use [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (without SCSS) as the front-end framework for my web project. When it comes to customization, I prefer not to modify any third-party modules referenced by my project, but use the cascading order rules of CSS to override whatever properties defined in the framework that I want to override. I have a tricky scenario here, however.

Foundation disables the user agent's `outline` property  for for `text:focused` with `text:focused {outline: none !important}`. Is there any way, without modifying the framework's CSS, to force the use of the user agent's `outline` property?

Comment: dont think there is a good way to do this... see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8228980/152640

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write another CSS rule that would reset the element's styling to default. In most cases, you could define a new rule to set the styling back to most user agent defaults:

```
text:focused { outline: solid black 1px; }
```

Unfortunately, you won't be able to override Foundation's `!important` declaration with CSS.  However, you can do so with JavaScript; something like this:

```
document.theText.style.outline = "solid black 1px";
```

(I didn't test this, but I could if you provide a JSFiddle demo of your scenario.)