# How do I escape a style for specific elements in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider an example of input text field.

```css
input[type='text']{
   border:none;
   border-bottom:2px solid #666;
}
```

```html
With style <br/>
<input type='text'/> 

<br/>

How do I escape the default style for the below one and display a regular input field without any style applied to it? 
<br/>

<input type='text'/>
```

I am using a css framework and I don't want to alter the css page of the framework. So how do I escape the default style for the input field and display a regular input field without any style applied to it?

Is there any specific term for not applying style or escaping it?

Comment: seems like it's just one input you want to exclude from the styles and you don't want to alter the css file, you have to use inline styling for it. 
`<input type='text' style="your default styles for input here">`

Comment: I think your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458648/how-to-set-css-attributes-to-default-values-for-a-specific-element-or-prevent-i)