# Remove a class property with a media query on a mobile first design?

Tags: css

I have tab elements with either `display: inline` or `none` depending if they are selected. Eg:

```
<div class="tab" style="display:inline;"></div>
<div class="tab" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then a class in my stylesheet overrides the display property so that all tabs are shown in mobile devices:

```
.tab {
display: block !important;
}
```

My problem is that I need to prevent this condition to apply to screen bigger than 600px but I cannot use max-width queries. So I need to override `display: block !important` with a min-width media query without applying any other particular style. Eg:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
.tab  {
display: /*don't do anything*/ !important; 
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `!important`?

Comment: "_don't do anything_"? you might want to apply some other value to the  display property. If it so, then use  `div.tab` instead of just mentioning `.tab` and give `display: inline;` (or some other value). [side note] `!important` leads to bad designing.

Comment: I need to use !important to override all element style attributes. I don't see any other way of doing this.

Comment: You can't reset the previous values using just css though.. check this [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8229026/1577396).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mark selected tab by class name `class='selected'`, can try this way:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab selected">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tab {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .tab  {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab.selected {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LybCr/)

Comment: Adding a working demo is a really good way to show that your solution works.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. And I would do it like this have I written the js but it's using jquery-ui which add the style="display:block" or "display:none" instead of a class to the element.

Comment: I noticed jquery-ui uses `aria-expanded="true"` when a tab is selected so I'll use the attribute as .tab.selected. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to avoid using inline styles and `!important` whenever possible try something like:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jncs6/)**

HTML

```
<div class="tab selected">Hello world!</div>
<div class="tab">Good bye world!</div>
```

CSS

```
.tab {
    display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .tab {
        display: none;
    }
    .selected {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all: do not use style="" on your HTML. You cannot override the css attributes from an external CSS, even using !important.

I recommend you using only external CSS files, then, let's say you want to override attributes the thing would come this way:

```
.tab {
display: inline;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
.tab {
display: block, inline or none;
}
}
```