# Div display:initial not working as intended in ie10 and chrome 29

Tags: html, css

I want to display a div with the following restrictions:

- automatically hide under 1024px width
- can be toggle by button under 1024px width, but if I click somwhere (not inside the div) the `activeDiv` class should be removed

I have a dummy example at [codepen](http://codepen.io/rpety/pen/Imbyw)

So the following problems occured:

- In IE10 the toggle button just not work (not hide/show the div) I check with the developer tools, but no sign of the `display: initial`
- In Chrome 29 the div appeard next the button not under it. (Firefox is the same)
  I know that the default `display` for div is `block`, but this css is not only for `div` tags that's why I try to use `initial`.

Comment: The `initial` keyword isn't [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keywords) in any version of IE

Comment: Ohh. I didn't know that. But that page claims that the 'auto' is supported and still not working with that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`initial` does *not* mean "the default value of a given property for a given element". It means "the default value of a given property as defined by the spec". The initial value of `display` is `inline`, not `block`, as stated [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop). This is regardless of what sort of element you apply it to. And as already mentioned, IE does not support the `initial` keyword.

If you want an element to be displayed as a block, use `display: block`. If you want it to be displayed inline, use `display: inline`. If you want it to use whichever is the browser default for it, *do not set* the `display` property at all.

Comment: I thought that the default value for display is block for the div tags. I try to override the value given by 'div' class (unfortunate name I know that now) if the width under 1024px with class activeDiv.

Comment: It is, but that's not what `initial` means.

Comment: So there is no value to set the original default value back? Like 'default' or something? If I change the default value I can't reset it?

Comment: @Péter No, unfortunately there isn't.

Comment: More about this can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228980/28324. TL;DR: the new CSS [`revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-revert) keyword is supposed to pick the default value for the element, but it is not well-supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by this?

> this css is not only for div tags

display:initial is CSS3 and not supported by IE10. If no display-rule is specified it can inherit from, it will fall back to display:inline.

```
display:block;
display:initial;
```

provides a fallback display:block.

Comment: The chrome also messing with the initial. The div appears next to the button, not under it. Under 'this css is not only for div tags' I mean that that div is just an example, and intend to use these classes on other elements for example 'span' which is inline by default.