# Why I cant see html element on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I work on my angularjs project.

I created HTML view that changes modes from display view to edit view by click on the button.

I created css class named `edit-mode`.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4n9yxyHZJnEonqzkcOf1?p=preview).

Here is my view:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-sm">
  <div ng-class="{'edit-mode':editor.edit}">

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <span class="view">{{ma.inspection}}</span>
        <textarea cols="20" rows="2" my-maxlength="5" ng-model="ma.inspection" class="form-control edit"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="editor.edit = false" value="Display mode">
    <input type="button" ng-click="editor.edit = true" value="Edit mode">

  </div>
</form>
```

Here is controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('MyApp', [function() {
  var self = this;
  this.inspection = "Click on button to change mode!";

}]);
```

Here is my css code:

```
.edit, input[type=file].edit {

    display: none;
}

.edit-mode {
    .view {
        display: none;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .edit, input[type=file].edit {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

The code above works perfect in chrome browser.
But it not works on IE browser(I use IE 11) the textarea element and select element not displayed .

Any Idea how can I fix this problem,to make this work also on IE browser?

Comment: I am using IE 11 .

Comment: What is the issue exactly? `Not works on IE browser`, there are tons of things that can't work here. I can't visit plunker from work.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude , I updated question.

Comment: The problem is `display='initial'` change it to `display='block'`.

Comment: Initial doesn't work in IE. Change to `display: inline`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`initial` keyword doesn't work on IE. That's fine, the correct behaviour of IE (nothing works). But to fix your problem, write the correct that's `inline` for form elements.

```
 display: inline
```

And for textarea

```
 display: inline-block
```

Final code:

```
.edit-mode {
    .view {
        display: none;
        background-color:red;
    }

    .edit, input[type=file].edit {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `display='initial'` change it to `display='block'`. 
Refer the link below:
[Div display:initial not working as intended in ie10 and chrome 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851042/div-displayinitial-not-working-as-intended-in-ie10-and-chrome-29)

Comment: form elements are display inline and inline-block, not block.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was just curious to say initial doesn't work. Thats why I posted a link here.Thanks.@MarcosPérezGude

Comment: You are welcome. I only notice you, with the purpose you can learn what's the initial value in some elements. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Like all the other answers say, `display:initial;` is not supported by IE. Therefore, the best cross browser solution with AngularJS is to use `ng-show` to dynamically hide elements, instead of CSS.

I've tested this to work on Internet Explorer 11. Note how I don't use the classes.

```
<body>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <div ng-controller="MyApp as ma">

    <form class="form-horizontal form-sm">
      <!--<div ng-class="{'edit-mode':editor.edit}">-->

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <span ng-init="editor.edit=false" ng-show="editor.edit == false">{{ma.inspection}}</span>
            <textarea cols="20" rows="2" ng-show="editor.edit == true" my-maxlength="5" ng-model="ma.inspection" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" ng-click="editor.edit = false" value="Display mode">
        <input type="button" ng-click="editor.edit = true" value="Edit mode">

      <!--</div>-->
    </form>



  </div>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.controller('MyApp', [function() {

      // default 
      editor = {};
      editor.edit = false;

      var self = this;
      this.inspection = "Click on button to change mode!";

    }]);
  </script>
</body>
```