# How can i exclude a CSS property?

Tags: css

I have the following style applied in an Unordered list `<ul class ="page-title"> </ul>`

```
.page-title {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 23px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  margin: 20px 0px 15px 0px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I would like to add an extra style to the div which when applied, remove the font-weight property.

<s>font-weight: 300;</s>

Is this possible or i need vacation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unapply a property in CSS, but you can override it with the default

```
font-weight: normal;
```

Comment: It’s not “the default”, just the initial value. The default value could well be `bold` (if the element is `h1` for example). In general, setting a property to its initial value *or* to its default value for an element is not equivalent to striking out a declaration from somewhere. For all that we can know, some other style could set the property, and then you would be overriding that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
font-weight: initial;
```

to reset it to the CSS default. This *may* however be overridden by your browser, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value), so you may want to look up what the default is some other way and set it via Javascript (for example).

Comment: Where is `initial` supported? I've not seen that in the specifications. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness

Comment: It is pointless to set `font-weight: initial`, since it is equivalent to `font-weight: normal` but with limited browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
font-weight: inherit;
```

...to set it back to the previous value, or...

```
font-weight: normal;
```

...to explicitly set it to normal non-bold weight.