# Showing messages and errors to users, alternative to alert()

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a [Chrome extension](https://github.com/Cacodaimon/GhostTextForChrome) that'll need to display some messages to the users, be them instructions or errors. Right now the former are completely missing and errors are displayed in `alert` boxes.

We came up with this

- `alert(message);` Not great, especially for instructions. Currently used.
- `chrome.notifications` are not meant to be used this way: they appear off-center and disappear before the user may be done reading.
- appending html content to the current tab, which we see as a last resort since we don't want to risk conflicts

Is there a better way to inform the user?

Comment: Open a new tab/popup would be an option.

Answer (score 2):

There is some other ways to do that, although none of them can be what you are looking for. Anyway, I'll share my solutions

**1) Customizing default popup**

You can append customized content to your popup window and let your users informed by setting the badge text:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "error"})
```

*See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText*

I think this is the best solution to **show errors** because your user won't be annoyed

**2) Creating a new tab**

To **show instructions** most extensions I used creates a new tab

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: "instructions.html"});
```

*See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create*

This occurs usually after the user installs the extension.

Comment: 1) The problem with the popup solution is that we're already using that button as an on/off button, so we can't also have a popup. If we enable the popup it will open on every click.

Comment: 2) Showing instructions in a new tab could be good for the first usage, but I'd rather show any possible message in-context, without moving the user's focus away

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using [humane.js](http://wavded.github.io/humane-js/) to show messages on the page since it only required [two small files](https://github.com/Cacodaimon/GhostTextForChrome/tree/master/vendor), both of which have been "isolated" to avoid any possible CSS class clash with the existing content.

Still not ideal since I'd rather not having to add any elements/CSS to the page, but that's the best we got now.

Comment: You should look into [Shadow DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897395/how-to-reset-all-styles-of-a-div-and-decedents-back-to-chrome-defaults/20901571#20901571) to provide isolation you need.

Comment: Doesn't that still need an element to fill the shadow DOM with?

Comment: It's still less intrusive than a whole UI, and no chance of a style clash. In theory, at least.