# How to solve the conflict between reset.css/normalize.css and the 'initial' CSS prop value?

Tags: html, css

There is a new value in CSS3 called 'initial', it will reset the prop's value to the browser's default.

The spec here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

But in most times, a website/webpage often have a reset.css or normalize.css file apply to the site/page.

So in most cases, I want the prop which set to 'initial' to be the reset.css or normalize.css's value but not the browser's default, how to solve the conflict between those two?

Comment: Why not just use the same value as in the `reset.css` then? It's a constant, so there are no issues with changing it. Can you show a specific example where you have a problem with this?

Comment: most times the developer can not remember the value in the reset.css, is it?

Answer (score 3):

> There is a new value in CSS3 called 'initial', it will reset the prop's value to the browser's default.

That's where most people are mistaken ([even I got it wrong once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value/8229026#8229026)). The initial value is *not* the same thing as the browser's default value.

A browser default is set by the browser in its default stylesheet.

The initial value of a property is the default that is stated in the spec. The initial value is usually the same regardless of what element you apply the property to; it's the browser that decides whether it should apply a different value to different elements by default.

For example, the initial value of `display` is `inline` — many HTML elements default to `display: block`, but setting `display: initial` will turn them into inline elements, *not* block elements.

Even the document you link to itself links to another document [defining the term "initial value"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value):

> The **initial value** given in the summary of the definition of each CSS property has different meaning for inherited and non-inherited properties.

With all that said, there is currently no way using CSS to reset a property to either a browser's default *or* an arbitrary level in the cascade (e.g. normalize.css or a reset stylesheet).

Comment: This is a great answer and should be accepted. There is now a postcss plugin you can use to leverage some aspects of `initial` https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-initial