# Display: initial for internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, slideshow, displaytag, displayobject

I've made a website that works just fine in Google Chrome and Firefox, but when I run it in Internet Explorer I'm experiencing problems.

So, I have 2 slideshows on my index page but only one should show at a specific screen resolution. I created some media queries so i could set a `display:none;` to the slideshow I don't need at that resolution. And to make it appear again I use `display:initial;` but Internet Explorer doesn't support that command.

**I need a way to make visible what I had invisible with `display:none;` in Internet Explorer.**

PS: Using `visibility:hidden;` is not an option because it shouldn't reserve the space.

If you can help me, please reply.
If you can't I thank you for reading this anyway.

Here is come of the code; it might help (I'm not sure how to post correctly, sorry):

```
<section id="containerGrotePage">
    <div id="page">
    <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="images/slideshow/image2.jpg" alt="slideshow foto 1" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slideshow/image1.jpg" alt="slideshow foto 2" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slideshow/image3.jpg" alt="slideshow foto 3" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/slideshow/image4.jpg" alt="slideshow foto 4" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</section>

<div id="pageKlein">
    <ul id="sliderKlein">
        <li id="kleineSlideLi">
            <img id="fotoslideshowKlein" src="images/slideshow/image1.jpg" alt="slideshow foto 1" />
        </li>
    </ul>
<button onclick="slideshowKlein()" id="indexkleineSlideshowKnop">volgende</button>
</div>
```

This is what I do on the smallest screen :

```
#containerGrotePage{
display:none;
}
#page{
display:none;
}       
#kleineSlideLi{
background-color:black;
padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
}
#fotoslideshowKlein{
width:90%;
margin-left:4%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
#indexkleineSlideshowKnop{
width:90%;
margin-top:1%;
margin-left:4%;
}
```

first media query min:440px

```
@media only screen and (min-width:440px){
#container{
    margin-top:3%;
}

/*--slideshow--*/
#page {
    display:initial;
    width:600px; 
    margin:50px auto;
}
#slider {
    width:600px; 
    height:250px;

/*IE bugfix*/
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

media query min:610px

```
#slider li { 
list-style:none; 
}

#containerGrotePage{
display:initial;
display:block;
width:600px;
margin-top:2%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#pageKlein{
display:none;
}
#page {
    display:initial;
width:600px; 
margin:50px auto;
}
#slider {
width:600px; 
height:250px;

/*IE bugfix*/
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

media query min:715px

```
#slider {
width:600px;
height:250px;

/*IE bugfix*/
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#slider li {
    list-style:none;
}

#page {
width:600px;
margin:50px auto;
}
```

I hope the information I provided is useful.

ContainerGrotePage is the big slideshow, BTW and pageklein is the small one.
I speak Dutch, so some names might not make sense to English speakers. :)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: what version of internet explorer?

Comment: would be better if you can post a website link as well.

Comment: @omegaiori use Internet Explorer version 11.

Comment: @Kheema Pandey: I can't give you a link, the website isn't online yet. Work in progress. :)

Comment: why do you use display:initial instead of a simple display:block or display:visible ?

Comment: @omegaiori: display:block; made all my images blocks so they all stood under eachother. display:visible doesn't do anything.

But display:inline; however solves it. I Feel clumsy for overlooking that for so long.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Ps: you have to press "allow blocked content" for the slideshow to appear. I'm not sure why, could that have anything to do with the JQuery? Just curious.

Comment: that's dumb internet explorer don't worry it's normal :)

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution that allows you to do it in IE and Chrome. [Here](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/javascript-doesn-work-t76999.html), scroll to the bottom.

Long story short, [IE doesn't accept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530751(v=vs.85).aspx) `display = "initial"`. So the trick is doing it with `display = ""` instead. I.e.,

```
if(...){
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "";
}
else{
    a.style.display = "";
    b.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't exactly the same as setting the value `initial`, however this is more likely to be in line with what the reader is trying to do. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value) for details.

Answer (score 8):

This functions in a css file, if you need to set initial (both lines):

display: inline;

display: initial;

Comment: downvoted: Misleading. Here the display initial is not interprated by the browser

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue, and display: block or display: inline will show the content in IE. However, we were using classes to hide/show layout content responsively and would have needed to have 2 sets of classes, one for block and one for inline content.

That didn't make sense when considering that display: none and display: initial works fine in non-IE browsers (tested firefox/chrome/safari on windows, mac, android, and iPhone).

In the end, I found it much easier to use jQuery $(".class").hide() and $(".class").show() to handle this within a function that was run initially after the page loads, then re-called from a window resize event handler.

Comment: You could use the same class (like bootstrap `.hide`/`.show`) but just use a different `display` value based on the tag name (`div.hide`, `span.hide`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `hidden` attribute:

```
a.setAttribute('hidden', '')
b.removeAttribute('hidden')
```

It's supported in all major browsers including IE11. To get IE10 support, you need a couple of CSS lines:

```
[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```