# Removing a parent style on CSS hierarchy

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to override a css class to improve the site when looking in a small screen. Here is the e.g.

My file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
margin: 0;
}
```

Core file:

```
.fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
margin: 0;
padding: 100px 0 80px 0;
}
```

This way, the DIV that I wanna override, is getting the padding of the Core file... 
To be the way that I want, I couldn't put the padding style on my file. I need to "remove" this style!

How can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How css styling occurs is all the parent styling is automatically inherited by all the children elements and if you want to override any of the parent style you then have to specify it in the child element css style.

Suppose we have

```
.parent{color:red;}
```

then all the child elements will have the css style `color: red` . If you want to override it in child elements then 
you have to specify in child element css style `color:black`

Now in your case, your parent styling have `padding: 100px 0 80px 0;` if you do not want it in child then just do `padding: 0px;`

So it should look like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
   body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
     margin: 0;padding :0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the padding put:
`padding: 0`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `initial` keyword. Please check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial).

The `initial` keyword resets the inherited style to the default style according to CSS specifications. However, this is supported since CSS3 only and it looks like you need to add workarounds for **Internet Explorer**.

The similar `unset` keyword is even worse in terms of browser compatibility but maybe better suited to what you want.

You may also want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980) for related information.

---

**Note:** Most of the answers here think the asker wants to remove the padding. What the asker wants to do is remove the parent style (restoring the padding to what the browser would have put if the style wasn't mentioned in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing the curly brackets from your media query.

You have:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
margin: 0;
}
```

what you should have is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
   body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: He wanted the **padding** removed too. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
    body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
    margin: 0;
}
```

to this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
    body.layout-mode-responsive .fp-roksprocket-showcase.rt-block {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

You forgot to close your selector properly too.