# padding:initial vs. padding:0

Tags: html, css, keyword

Does `padding:initial` have any advantage over `padding:0`? Example:

```
<style>
  textarea {
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<textarea>Hello, world!</textarea>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They mean the same thing, as the initial value of `padding` is, in fact, zero on all sides. You can find this in the propdefs for `padding` and its longhands in [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) of the spec.

In this case, given the nature of the `padding` property, and the fact that its initial value is basically common knowledge at this point, there isn't much of an advantage of setting `padding: initial` over `padding: 0`.

In fact, there's one *disadvantage*, and that is its as yet incomplete browser support owing to the fact that it's a relatively new keyword. Namely, if `padding` wasn't already zero on this element, browsers that don't support the keyword would ignore the declaration entirely, resulting in the property *not* being reset to zero.

---

The `initial` keyword is most useful when used with the new properties defined in the [CSS3 Cascading module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade) (none of which are implemented yet AFAIK, and where the keyword itself is defined). It can also be used when you simply want to reset a property to its initial value without caring what that value actually is, which is particularly useful for properties that are either inherited by default, such as `color` (although the initial value in that case would be `currentColor`), or in cases where the "initial" value can otherwise vary depending on the layout and thus *cannot* be determined as a fixed value. Such cases, however, are admittedly quite rare.

Lastly, note that "initial value" and "browser default value" are not the same; the initial value is defined by spec, which is separate from what value the browser assigns to certain properties on certain elements as part of its default stylesheet. There is no reliable way to reset a property to its browser default for the given element without using prior knowledge or even JavaScript to determine this default value. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value/8229026#8229026) for an illustration.

Comment: More on this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Comment: Then What is the use of specifying initial??

Comment: If there's no difference whatsoever, then why is the `initial` keyword added to CSS3?

Comment: So initial is an Common keyword .. "The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element. It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the element for which it is specified to use the initial value of the property."

Comment: initial gives the developer more freedom. Examples can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: "_In fact, there's one disadvantage, and that is its as yet incomplete browser support owing to the fact that it's a relatively new keyword._" IMO, it has another _disadvantage_ too: `padding:0;` is easier/faster to read and understand what's going on the stylesheet.

Comment: @Hermes: Yeah but that's subjective - it depends on the person reading the CSS. I'm only listing objective/factual disadvantages to keep the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy both are same,But `Initial` gives the developer more freedom.(@simon's comment)It cannot be always zero,it can be any initial value.

**So there isn't much advantage of using padding: initial over
 padding: 0**

> The initial CSS keyword applies the initial value of a property to an element.  It is allowed on every CSS property and causes the
>   element  for which it is specified to use the initial value of the
>   property.

**Another Example**

```
<p style="color:red"> 
    this text is red 
       <em style="color:initial"> 
          this text is in the initial color (e.g. black)
       </em>
    this is red again
 </p>
```

read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: The keyword `initial` *always* means the initial value, not a “default value”. The question was specifically about `padding: initial`, so using `initial` for other properties, if mentioned as a side note, should be clearly distinguished from the answer to the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: thanks for your valuable suggestion! i will edit my answer.!