# why list element dont show up properly using display initial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>
.show{
   display : none;
}
</style>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
       var clickElement = document.getElementById("wow");
        clickElement.onclick = function(){
             $(".show").css('display', 'initial');
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
    <li id="wow">select</li>
    <li class="show">select1</li>
    <li class="show">select2</li>
    <li class="show">select3</li>

 </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

when I clicked, on the select, the selection list not show up properly but instead they show up inline, why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the `display` type to `list-item` rather than the `initial` value; Because the `initial` value of `display` property is `inline`. This is documented in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop).

The `initial` keyword refers to the value [defined by CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop), not the browser default.

Alternatively, you could use jQuery `.show()` method to achieve that.

For further reading:

- [Reset CSS display property to default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value)

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
$(".show").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `list-item` instead of `initial`.

Replace this line:

```
$(".show").css('display', 'initial');
```

with:

```
$(".show").css('display', 'list-item');
```

Source: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display