# how to remove the space occupied by hidden divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have set of divs as listed below,

```
<div id="invoice"></div>
<div id="claim"></div>
<div id="draft"></div>
```

and i have a reponse which may have type as invoice, claim or draft.
If I get "draft" in the response then I will display only claim div and rest two will be hidden, but the problem is the above two divs are hidden and occupying space also (i.e., leaving a gap from the top and then displaying the draft div).

I am using CSS as below,

```
 $("#draft").css('flex','flex-wrap'); // for showing the content in a straight line.
 $("#draft").css('display','block');
```

and for hiding it,

```
 $("#draft").css('display','none');
```

Similarly for all the id. I am new to this, so please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using display:none, there is no space being taken up - if you use visibility:hidden, there is. In this case it is the flex that is breaking it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144702/how-to-reset-display-property-for-flex-item

Comment: I am not sure how display:none is occupying space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your question below answer might be helpful.

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
}
div.anyOne:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
Div which has some data will be visible
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="invoice" class="anyOne">Invoice</div>
<div id="claim" class="anyOne"></div>
<div id="draft" class="anyOne"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none;` to hide an element completely and leaving its space.

Use `visiblity: hidden` to hide an element while leaving the space where it would have been.

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#draft {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="invoice">invoice</div>
<div id="claim">claim</div>
<div id="draft">draft</div>
<div id="another">another</div>
```