# I want to restore browser default style

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I am trying to change a text field's border using javascript

```
field.style.border='2px solid red';
```

that's working, then I want to restore the default style of browser after 2 or 3 seconds

I have done something like this

```
function shine(field){
        field.focus();
        field.style.border='2px solid red';
        setTimeout(function(){
            field.style.border='initial';
        },2000);
    }
```

but the attribute  initial is not helping.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried `field.style.border='';` ?

Comment: Also it's worth taking a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just set it to "" as stated in the related question.

```
element.style.border = ""
```

This will restore the css value provided.

You can check quick [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tawoxuwabu/1/), I've created

Comment: thanks, it works :)

and excuse me, will IE support this?

Comment: Well, the question was closed as a duplicate already, and the answers in the other question suggest that you should use `''` instead of `null`, especially for IE.