# Distinguish between used and computed values returned from getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, css

The MDN documentation for [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) states

> The values returned by getComputedStyle are known as resolved values.
>   These are usually the same as the CSS 2.1 computed values, but for
>   some older properties like width, height or padding, they are instead
>   the used values.

Is there a way to only get the **computed** values without the **used** ones?

*My use case is this:*

Take for instance a body element. The browsers width is currently `600px`. If you call `getComputedStyle` on the `body` element, the style returned would contain `width: 600px`.

Resize the browser and the width will be different again, although the "correct" value should probably be `auto`.

I'd need the returned style to be idempotent, meaning that I can set the style back on the element without changing some values (like `width`) to fixed values.

Comment: why should the correct value after resize should be auto for computedStyle

Comment: Well, I'd expect that setting the style on the element returned from its `getComputedStyle` would be idempotent. But as it is now this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given element and style property you would need the first of:

1. A value that has been explicitly applied to an element (through the `style` attribute or CSS)
2. The browser's default value for that property

You cannot do that reliably because the CSS spec [does not provide a way to access the browser's default CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value).