# Why does this not transition while the height does change?

Tags: css

Why does this not transition while the height does change.

```
<div class="text-container">
    <div class="heading"><p>Foo</p></div>    
    <div class="story"><p>BAR BAR BAR BAR BAR BAR BAR </p></div>  
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.text-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 0;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: red;
    transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
}

.story {
    display: none;
}

.text-container:hover .story {
    display: initial;
}
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/k00nhsbb/

Comment: You can't transition the `display property` in CSS. You would have to transition the `opacity property.`

Comment: Also you *really* don't want to use `display: initial` in any circumstance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value/8229026#8229026

Comment: CSS is so poor designed.

Comment: @dowomenfart that doesn't work either https://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/k00nhsbb/3/

Comment: @clankill3r you have to take off the `display: block` and  `display: none;` Try this out [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k00nhsbb/5/)