# Can't use children with :not pseudo selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble using some relatively simple CSS selectors using `:not`. Namely, the following selector is giving me an error:

```
a:not(.ebook_document *)
```

I am trying to get all `<a>` elements that are not children of the element with class `ebook_document`. This also fails:

```
a:not(.ebook_document > *)
```

As well as this:

```
a:not(.ebook_document, *)
```

Putting the selectors on their own, not in a  `:not` section works fine. What have I done wrong?

Comment: :not only takes a _simple_ selector. Plus, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not - _"This selector only applies to one element; you cannot use it to exclude all ancestors. For instance, `body :not(table) a` will still apply to links inside of a table, since <tr> will match with the :not() part of the selector."_ What you want is not possible using :not.

Comment: @CBroe ok, that answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:not only takes a [*simple*](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#simple-selectors-dfn) selector. (For now, CSS 4 expands that to a [selector list](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#selector-list).)

Plus, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not -

> This selector only applies to one element; you cannot use it to exclude all ancestors. For instance, `body :not(table) a` will still apply to links inside of a table, since  will match with the :not() part of the selector."

What you want is not possible using :not.

You can only go about it the other way around - format all "normal" links, and then apply different formatting for the links inside the target element(s) using `.ebook_document a { ... }`

So that means rather than not applying styles to those links in the first place, you might need to overwrite the styles you don't like for those links again.

(Or use [`initial`/`all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value) to actually reset styles, but browser support for that is still lacking AFAIK.)

Comment: Thank you. What I ended up doing was just finding all `<a>` elements and checking their ancestry with javascript, since performance doesn't matter at all for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm shouldn't it just be a:not(.ebook_document)? I didn't test it but it seems that that should reference all the a tags that don't have a .ebook_document tag.

Comment: I want all a tags that are not a child of a .ebook_document, even if they do not have a .ebook_document class on them theirself.