# CSS not honouring display initial

Tags: css

I can't workout how to get the second paragraph to display in this example code.  I've only tried it in Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    display: none;
}
.show {
    display: initial;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>para 1</p>
<div class="show">
    <p>para 2</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by setting `display` of `body` itself to none?

Comment: because you have `display:none` on the `body`, so everything inside the `body` wont display

Comment: So the <div> doesn't override?

Comment: you hid the body, and once you hide an element, everything INSIDE that element is also hidden.

Comment: How do I override that?

Comment: what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I guess you want something like `p {display: none} .show p {display: initial}`?

Comment: What I am looking for is to know how to get the second paragraph to display...

Comment: Well to get the second paragraph to display you need the body to also display. Oh and [initial doesn't do what you think it does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228980/reset-css-display-property-to-default-value/8229026#8229026).

Comment: display:initial must follow the parent element's display value

Comment: Yes, I see that.  I'd really want to the default to be off in some circumstances, just showing a few paragraphs.  But I guess that can't be done.

I tried inline first, but that didn't show either.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  visibility:hidden}
.show {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<p>para 1</p>
<div class="show">
    <p>para 2</p>
</div>
```

you can try this instead

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with this:

p {display: none} .show p {display: initial}

It's more work for me, but it does what I want.  Thanks.