# How do I select all elements on the page expect for a given element and all it's descendants?

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide all content on a page besides a given element and all of it's children using CSS.

Right now, I'm looking into the :not selector, but I haven't been able to get it working with the * selector.

```
:not(.list-app) {
    display: none;
}

:not(.list-app *) {
    display: none;
}
```

The above code is able to target the parent ".list-app" but I'm not able to target the children of the element.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ahh gotcha.  Yeah I'm using JS now but I was hoping for something a little more performant.  Right now, I'm selecting everything in the <body> of the page excluding the parent element that I want to preserve and am hiding it that way.  I guess I'll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible **with CSS alone**, barring a less-than-ideal workaround.

The [Selectors 3 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation) states that `:not()` requires a *simple selector*, which is why your initial attempt doesn't work.

The first thought for a workaround would be a simple override, but this has a major caveat: all children of the "excluded" parent would have to be overriden with the same `display`  type:

```css
body * { display: none; } 

.list-app, .list-app * { 
  display: block !important;  /* Every child is now display: block */
}
```

```html
<span>Hello world</span>
<div class="list-app">
  <span>Hi world</span>
</div>
```

For some more insight as to why this workaround's caveat exists, we can refer to [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229026/2026606) by BoltClock, to an older related question:

> A browser's default styles are defined in its user agent stylesheet, the sources of which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements). Unfortunately, the [Cascading and Inheritance level 3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3) does not appear to propose a way to reset a style property to its browser default. However there are plans to reintroduce a keyword for this in [Cascading and Inheritance level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#valdef-all-revert) — the working group simply hasn't settled on a name for this keyword yet (the link currently says `revert`, but it is not final). Information about browser support for `revert` can be found on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=revert).
>
> While the level 3 spec does introduce an [`initial` keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial), setting a property to its **initial value** resets it to its default value **as defined by CSS**, *not as defined by the browser*. The initial value of `display` is `inline`; this is specified [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop). The `initial` keyword refers to that value, not the browser default.